# So many entries in Grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I've just installed Kubuntu 15.04 on the Asus T200TA laptop which came with Windows 8.1 preinstalled.
I have the following options available:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
- Windows Boot UEFI loader
- EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/mmcblk0p2)
- Ubuntu 15.04 (15.04) (on /dev/mmcblk0p5)
- Advanced options for Ubutu 15.04 (15.04) (on /dev/mmcblk0p5)
- System setup

Why are there so many entries in the grub menu? Why did the "15.04" entries suddenly appear after running `sudo update-grub`?

**EDIT:** I installed another Ubuntu flavor on /dev/mmcblk0p6. Now I have two more entries

- Ubuntu 15.04 (on /dev/mmcblk0p6)
- Advanced options Ubuntu 15.04 (on /dev/mmcblk0p6)

Now in all advanced options I have 5 entries called "Ubuntu 15.04". I can't see 4.1.2 kernel there.

I'd rather have a more tidy boot menu (which would persists after `update-grub`:

- Kubuntu
- Kubuntu (advanced)
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu (advanced)
- Windows

Comment: Did you do a dual boot setup?  On mine, System Setup is apparently supposed to take you to BIOS, but just reboots.  Windows Boot Manager starts Windows.  The others look like artifacts of UEFI ( I don't have those entries).

Comment: Yes, this is a dual boot setup with UEFI

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 still use the 3.xx kernel serie: the 4.x one is not stable yet. See https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: Latest stable is 4.1.4. Installed 4.x manually

Answer (score 0):

All those entries correspond to different ways* of booting your kernels (in the case of Linux) or to give control to the windows bootloader. Also, grub keeps track of older kernels and propose you to use them to boot (when you'll have newer kernel installed).

[*] Those "ways" are option you can pass at boot time, to specify certain modules to load, or modify some module behaviour. For example, the recovery mode entry does not specify a `gfxmode` option, which result in the system booting without graphical interface.

I believe the 15.04 option comes from a new kernel package that was not present when you initially installed Ubuntu. The reason why you have a new entry for your new ubuntu flavor is that as the graphical environment change, grub needs a new entry to allow you booting with it.

You can modify their placement my changing the number of files in /etc/grub.d/[x][filename]. A very detailed tutorial is available [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17787/clean-up-the-new-ubuntu-grub2-boot-menu/)

As a side note, you may want to check [this resource](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/) to understand better the boot process in Linux.

Comment: Could you please some light what these ways are? What does MokManager do? What is the difference between the three entries? Plus, see the update of the OP